# Why can't I add to an array from another array inside a for loop

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, evaluation

```
<< DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`

baseFunctions = {AiryAi[#]^2 &, 
            AiryAiPrime[#]^2 &,
            AiryAiPrime[#] AiryAi[#] &
            };

(*Add all products of baseFunctions to combinedFunctions*)
For [i = 1, i <= Length[baseFunctions], i++,
  For [j = 1, j <= Length[baseFunctions], j++,
   Print[baseFunctions[[i]][#] baseFunctions[[j]][#] &]
     AppendTo[combinedFunctions, baseFunctions[[i]][#] baseFunctions[[j]][#] &];
   ]
  ];

Print[combinedFunctions];
```

When I print out, I am getting i and j in the combinedFunctions elements instead of the numbers they represent at that time in the for loop.

```
{baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[i]][#1] baseFunctions[[j]][#1]&}
```

I would like this to instead print out

```
{baseFunctions[[1]][#1] baseFunctions[[1]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[1]][#1] baseFunctions[[2]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[1]][#1] baseFunctions[[3]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[2]][#1] baseFunctions[[1]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[2]][#1] baseFunctions[[2]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[2]][#1] baseFunctions[[3]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[3]][#1] baseFunctions[[1]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[3]][#1] baseFunctions[[2]][#1]&,
baseFunctions[[3]][#1] baseFunctions[[3]][#1]&}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Function` (`... &`) has the HoldAll attribute, so no evaluation happens inside it until variables are replaced with their value. You need to enclose the body of the function in `Evaluate`: `Evaluate[baseFunctions[[i]][#] baseFunctions[[j]][#] ] &`. You also probably want a `;` to separate the Print and AppendTo statements.

Comment: Having said that, what is your ultimate goal? What you're doing looks a bit weird so I wonder if your actual goal might be achieved more easily .

Comment: Perhaps something like this might be useful: list = Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 2]; bFunctions /@ list   This maps the bFunctions over the list of all tuples

Comment: `Evaluate` solved it thank you! I'm just trying to come up with a bunch of candidates to try to spam brute force guess the solution to this ODE which I know inovlves the Airy function and kind of know how to solve in a special case.

Comment: Have you tried DSolve?  If your solution contains combinations of Airy functions, it's likely that DSolve will find them for you.

Comment: Please don't add [tag:bugs] tag unless the community or WRI has confirmed it. And as indicated by @MarcoB's comment, this is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion by Bill S is an example of how one can learn to shift from a programmatic to a functional style.  It is useful to learn this style.

Here is another:

```
baseFunctions = {AiryAi[\[FormalX]]^2, AiryAiPrime[\[FormalX]]^2, 
  AiryAiPrime[\[FormalX]] AiryAi[\[FormalX]]}
```

The [FormalX]]^2 has a nice display form. It is a symbol that cannot be assigned to a value.

Here is a matrix of all your products:

```
tmp = Outer[#1 #2 &, baseFunctions, baseFunctions]
```

The following creates function that uses that matrix:

```
f = Function[{\[FormalX]}, 
  Evaluate[Outer[#1 #2 &, baseFunctions, baseFunctions]]]
```

Then you can use the function as follows:

```
f[x]
```

or

```
f[2]
```

If you only want the six unique multiples:

```
f = Function[{\[FormalX]}, 
  Evaluate[
   Union@Flatten@Outer[#1 #2 &, baseFunctions, baseFunctions]]]
```